# Como proibir uma ação DDL no oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger

Eu quero fazer uma trigger que proiba qualquer operação DML em uma determinada tabela. No caso estes são os parâmetros: entre as 20:00 até 06:00, e domingo o dia todo.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TG_HORARIO
BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE OR INSERT
ON XNOTA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    D_SEMANA INT;
    HORA INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'd') INTO D_SEMANA FROM DUAL;
    SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24') INTO HORA FROM DUAL;
    IF D_SEMANA <> 7 THEN
        IF HORA < 6 AND HORA > 20 THEN
            RETURN FALSE;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

OBS.: Como devo proceder a partir do segundo if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TG_HORARIO
BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE OR INSERT
ON XNOTA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    D_SEMANA CHAR(1);
    HORA     CHAR(4);
BEGIN
    D_SEMANA := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'd');--SELECT NAO NECESSARIO
    HORA     := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24');
    IF ((D_SEMANA = '1' OR (HORA < '0600' AND HORA > '2000')) THEN--TESTE DO HORARIO domingo e 1
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'OPERACAO INVALIDA !!');
    END IF;
END;
```

Segue um exemplo , creio ser academico seu problema , em um caso real feriados talvez precisem ser tratados.